# angular js directive attribute and controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to have a directive which creates a `div` as title and a `ul` list under it.

I want the title to be set from attribute and a the list by a controller.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cYSr/) of my code

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <my-list caption="My List" ng-controller="ListController"></my-list>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
controller('ListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        caption: 'Item 1'
    }, {
        caption: 'Item 2'
    }, {
        caption: 'Item 3'
    }];
}]).directive('myList', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>' +
            '<div style="font-weight:bold;">{{caption}}</div>' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.caption}}</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>',
        scope: {
            caption: '@caption'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.find('li').on('click', function (evt) {
                alert($(this).html());
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed few things in your controller.

1. moved controller to div

   ```
   <div ng-app="myModule"  ng-controller="ListController">
       <my-list caption="My List" list="items"></my-list>
   </div>
   ```
2. fixed directive to receive list as a parameter

   ```
   directive('myList', [function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       template: '<div>' +
           '<div style="font-weight:bold;">{{caption}}</div>' +
           '<ul>' +
           '<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="onClick(item)">{{item.caption}}</li>' +
           '</ul>' +
           '</div>',
       scope: {
           caption: '@caption', items: '=list'
       },
       link: function (scope, element) {
           scope.onClick= function(item){console.log(item);}
       }
   }
   }])
   ```

there is one doubt though that i have.

controller `myList` to is tried to view or to directive?? in case it is tied to directive then

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
controller('ListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        caption: 'Item 1'
    }, {
        caption: 'Item 2'
    }, {
        caption: 'Item 3'
    }];
}]).directive('myList', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>' +
            '<div style="font-weight:bold;">{{caption}}</div>' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="onClick(item)">{{item.caption}}</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>',
        scope: {
            caption: '@caption'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.onClick= function(item){console.log(item);}
        },
        controller: 'ListController'
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem (as the error message indicates) is that you specify multiple directives which request for an isolated scope.

Actually, if you want to specify a controller for your directive, you use the `controller` property of the Directive Definition Object:

```
<my-list caption="My List"></my-list>

.directive('myList', [function () {
    return {
        ...
        controller: 'ListController', 
        ...
```

---

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/9cYSr/3/)**